# How to Prevent Tabs Being Replaced By Spaces in Content

Tags: emeditor

*EmEditor* has a configuration to replace (or not) tabs with spaces for indenting (at beginning of line), but this is **not** my question. Even with this box unchecked, I observe that if I have text content with tabs mixed in (*other* than beginning of line), then edit and save the document, all tabs are replaced with spaces. How can I prevent this behavior? I suspect it is a configuration but I cannot find it.
Version 20.4.4 on Windows 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

Found it from related questions *after* posting my question. Apologies.
For the given configuration (Text, SQL, etc) choose `Configuration Properties -> File -> Saving...`
Uncheck the box `Save Tabs as Spaces` !

[image: Configuration Dialog]